# SELinux access denied error for bash scripts triggered from perl-cgi script

Tags: linux, selinux

I have a automation framework which use Perl-CGI for running scripts at server. As we have SELinux enabled I am getting access denied errors when the script try to run a bash script.

Below is the error logs I can find in audit.log for the script

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1397170377.265:109255): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=23776 comm="run_step.sh" name="step.sh" dev=sda1 ino=795126 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1397170377.265:109255): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=23776 comm="run_step.sh" path="/var/www/html/test/generated.5465/step.sh" dev=sda1 ino=795126 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file
```

When I set SELinux in permissive mode I am able to run these scripts without any errors. But when it is enforcing I am not able to do so.

Also I have set the httpd labeling for the files but still getting these errors. Any thoughts how to resolve it.

Comment: I think you may have labelled the files incorrectly, try httpd_sys_script_t instead of httpd_sys_rw_content_t.

Comment: @Iain Looks like the right answer; I'd just go ahead and make it an answer.

Comment: Seems to be correct but right now I am not able to relabel the stuff as getting them labelled as httpd_sys_rw_content_t. So any thoughts how to reset them and get it labelled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the audit.log messages, it seems like you may have some of the files incorrectly labelled. If you are trying to run the files then I think they should be labelled `httpd_sys_script_t` rather than `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`.